# How to find the equation of a contour through a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y)=4xy-x^4-y^4$, with a saddle point at $(0,0)$ and maxima at $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$. The contour that passes through the saddle point appears to have the equation $r=2\sin(2\theta)$ by observation, but is this correct, and if so how is it derived?

Comment: It's not correct: Multiplying the polar equation by $r^2$ and using the double angle formula for sine gives$$r^3=2r^2\sin(2\theta)=4(r\cos\theta)(r\sin\theta) = 4xy.$$The level curve has equation $x^4+y^4=4xy$.